# Asus mb189b driver does not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: multiple-monitors

Where can I find working drivers from this USB monitor?
https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu
Here there are only for Ubuntu 18.04
When i try to install these one, this is the report:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good. 
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 4.4.24 DisplayLink Linux 
Software 4.4.24 install script called: install Distribution 
discovered: Ubuntu 18.10 
Installing Configuring EVDI DKMS module Registering EVDI kernel module 
with DKMS 
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS ERROR (code 3): Failed to build 
evdi/4.4.24. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/4.4.24/build/make.log for 
details.
```

Comment: Have yo tried the latest driver?

Comment: yes i tried for 18.04, nothing happens

Comment: If nothing happens you aren't doing it right. Something always happens when running a script. Weren't there any error messages?

Comment: Please [edit] and add all important info to the question.